# Request for Location Permissions in IOS 14 never returns

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having trouble requesting IOS Location permissions in Xamarin with the following code it works on IOS 15 and IOS 13 but never returns on IOS 14. I have found several places talking about it and using something like this but they are from 2020. Could something have changed recently to cause this issue again ?

```
while (true)
            {
                if (await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>() == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                    break;

               _ = Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
```

Xamarin Essentials 1.7.0

Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2125

Comment: That looks like very bad code.  You will be stuck in an infinite loop if location permissions aren't granted.  You shouldn't poll for location permissions.  The correct process is 1. Check the permission you have.  2. If it is `notDetermined` then ask for location.  3. Wait for the callback to the permission changed delegate method.  4. If the permission is anything other than `.notDetermined` then handle that; either use location if permission is granted or not if it is denied.

Comment: *"never returns on IOS 14"* - in other words, it never gets granted, on that device or emulated device. This will happen if user has previously **denied** the permission to your app. Paulw is correct - do not loop. Request the permission ONE TIME. The result will be whatever it is - then you need to react correspondingly. If the result indicates the user DENIED permission, then you either continue without location, or you bring up a dialog informing the user of the problem. In that dialog, give user an option to go to device's settings for the app, where they can MANUALLY turn permission on.

Comment: So it's bad code please provide an example of good code. I am really wanting the dialog to show up but it is not it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't loop waiting for a specific outcome.  iOS will show the request to the user once.  Once they have answered, that is the answer; The only exception is if they select "allow once" - You will get location permission but next time your app is launched, it will be as if you haven't asked and the dialog will be shown again.

If the user grants permission then you can use location.  If they deny permission then you can't - You either proceed without location or direct them to device settings for your app where they can grant location permission.

Obtaining the permission answer is asynchronous; It takes some time for the user to select a response.  The `await` handles this for you.

```
var permission = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>()

if (permission == PermissionStatus.Granted) {
    // Great - you can use location 
} else {
    // No location permission - You can't use it 
    // You can check the value of permission to see if location was denied or is unavailable 
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this and report back ... Even doing it one time I was not getting a dialog at all.

Comment: You have to check the location status for your app in the settings app.  If it is anything other than "ask next time" then you won't see the dialog.